# PowerShell's Get-Date and "Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target"

Tags: powershell

I am very confused of this error message:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

The problem line is:

```
$logondate = $(Get-Date $([datetime]::Parse( $user.LastLogonDate)) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

# User is vartype: System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
#$user.LastLogonDate in debug with this value: 10.06.2014 14:26:13 (dd.MM.yyyy)
```

What does this error mean?

From 30 [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) accounts there are only three with this ParameterBindingException.

Full error message:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\scripts\AD.ps1:309 char:28
+     $logondate = $(get-date <<<<  $([datetime]::Parse( $user.LastLogonDate)) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Comment: I'm guessing the user accounts in question does not have a value for that attribute. As in, they've never logged on.

Comment: You have right, but how to solve it?
Both code doesn't work:
  http://paste.ubuntu.com/7779328/
sry for link, I don't know how to format small comment here...

Comment: Try modifying your IF to something like this and see if that makes any difference;

if($user.LastLogonDate -gt $null) { <do-your-stuff> } else { Write-Output "never logged on" }

Comment: I found solution this way:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7779608/

Answer (score 2):

You get that error, because for some reason `Parse()` cannot parse `$user.LastLogonDate` into a date. Perhaps because the user never logged on (so the value is `$null`), or because `Parse()` doesn't recognize the default date format.

However, the `LastLogonDate` property (as created by `Get-ADUser`) already holds a `DateTime` value. What you're trying to do here is: implicitly convert the date to a string, parse that string back into a date, then create a formatted string from it again.

Don't.

Simply format the `DateTime` value you already have:

```
PS C:\> $user = Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Property *
PS C:\> $user.LastLogonDate.GetType().FullName
System.DateTime
PS C:\> $user.LastLogonDate

Monday, July 11, 2014 8:50:38 AM

PS C:\> $user.LastLogonDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
2014-07-07 08:50:38
```

Add a check for `$null` values to prevent errors for users that never logged on:

```
if ($u.LastLogonDate -ne $null) {
    $user.LastLogonDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
}
```